# Fourth argument in \RequirePackage internals?

Tags: macros, packages

I was reading the code of `miniltx` to understand the way LaTeX loads package files. I know it is simplified, but there's an aspect which is puzzling to me. According to `source2e`, `\RequirePackage` has the following template:

```
\RequirePackage[options]{name}[version]
```

It means it should take three arguments or less. However, both in the simplified definition of `\RequirePackage` and the full-fledged version of `source2e` the following happens more or less on the same lines:

```
\def\RequirePackage{%
  \@fileswithoptions\@pkgextension}
\def\@fileswithoptions#1{% Nice
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\@fileswith@ptions#1}%
    {\@fileswith@ptions#1[]}}
\def\@fileswith@ptions#1[#2]#3{% Nice
  \@ifnextchar[%]
  {\@fileswith@pti@ns#1[#2]#3}%
  {\@fileswith@pti@ns#1[#2]#3[]}}
```

And I'm stuck here. Why does a fourth argument appear and why is it enclosed by square brackets? (I've omitted some lines)

```
\def\@fileswith@pti@ns#1[#2]#3[#4]{% ???
    \def\reserved@b##1,{%
      \ifx\@nil##1\relax\else
        \ifx\relax##1\relax\else
         \noexpand\@onefilewithoptions##1[#2][#4]\noexpand\@pkgextension
        \fi
        \expandafter\reserved@b
      \fi}%
      \edef\reserved@a{\zap@space#3 \@empty}%
      \edef\reserved@a{\expandafter\reserved@b\reserved@a,\@nil,}%
  \reserved@a}

\def\@pkgextension{sty}

\def\@onefilewithoptions#1[#2][#3]#4{%
  \input #1.#4 }
```

I'm supposing it has to do with `.sty` suffix, but still, I don't figure out, especially because of square brackets in the fourth argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The macro `\@fileswithoptions` is also used to load *class* files. Indeed, you find

```latex
\def\LoadClass{%
  \ifx\@currext\@pkgextension
     \@latex@error
      {\noexpand\LoadClass in package file}%
      {You may only use \noexpand\LoadClass in a class file.}%
  \fi
  \@fileswithoptions\@clsextension}
```

As usual for macros with optional arguments, the arguments are picked up by using different macros. In this case the macro `\@fileswithoptions` stores its single argument and checks whether a `[` follows. If there is `[`, `\@fileswith@ptions#1` is called, otherwise `\@fileswith@ptions#1[]` (so an empty optional argument is supplied).

Note that `#1` will be either `\@pkgextension` or `\@clsextension` which has to be carried forward.

Next a regular argument is scanned, still carrying forward the first two arguments; then another optional one. The final macro, the one performing the real job, will therefore need *four* arguments.

In `latex.ltx` we see

```latex
\def\@fileswith@pti@ns#1[#2]#3[#4]{%
  \ifx#1\@clsextension
    \ifx\@classoptionslist\relax
      \xdef\@classoptionslist{\zap@space#2 \@empty}%
      \def\reserved@a{%
        \@onefilewithoptions#3[{#2}][{#4}]#1%
        \@documentclasshook}%
    \else
      \def\reserved@a{%
        \@onefilewithoptions#3[{#2}][{#4}]#1}%
    \fi
  [...]
```

and you see that the argument *is* used. In the abridged form used in `miniltx.tex`, argument `#1` is not actually used, because it makes no sense to load a class. So the code author decided not to use `#1` but also to stick with the standard definition when the arguments are picked up: only a few parts are streamlined.

Comment: Oh, I just tested it coloring arguments instead of doing a job and I understand your answer a lot better. Indeed, the first argument disappears. Such a convoluted way of giving arguments a different order.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument is going to be `\@pkgextension` Interestingly, unless you've deleted some lines in the definition of `\@fileswith@pti@ns`, that first argument isn't actually used anywhere.

Comment: The design spec for `miniltx.tex` was "don't generate errors loading latex code into plain" parsing arguments and not using them meets that spec admirably:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can confirm this.  Although it does not allow to load packages like LaTeX, packages which only rely on generic macros, e.g. those provided by PGF/TikZ and expl3, work with `miniltx` and a few tweaks.